# Incorrect proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the following

> Result:   Let   $n   ∈  \mathbb{Z}$. Then $5n+7$ is even only if $n$ is odd.

Next, consider the following proof.

Assume ﬁrst that $n$ is an odd integer. Then $n=2a+1$ for some integer $a$. Therefore, $5n+7=5(2a+1)+7=10a+5+7=10a+12=2(5a+6)$.  Since $5a+6$ is an integer, $5n+7$ is even.

Next, assume that $n$ is an even integer. Then $n=2b$ for some integer $b$. Hence $5n+7=5(2b)+7=10b+7=2(5b+3)+1$.  Since $5b+3$ is an integer, $5n+7$ is odd.

- this proof is solved incorrectly but I can't figure out what is wrong with it. It is solved as if it were a bi-conditional statement and it seems to be taking the correct steps to solving one but I see nothing wrong with it. I was also  thinking that It might not be a bi-conditional statement to begin with. I'm at a loss here. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think this is solved incorrectly? How would you solve it differently?

Comment: The proposition uses “only if,” not “if and only if,” so it’s not a biconditional. It claims nothing about $5n+7$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: @amd I would be more inclined to say that the statement is incomplete, not that the proof is wrong.

Comment: You have correctly proved a different result that is stronger than the one you were requested to prove. But, unfortunately, this proof doesn't show if you have understood the meaning of “only if”, which probably was the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: @David I didn’t say that the proof was incorrect, but that half of it is extraneous. The proposition *as stated* by the OQ isn’t a biconditional, so proving “if $n$ is odd, then $5n+7$ is even” is irrelevant. It’s the wrong direction. I’m with egreg—understanding the meaning of “only if” was likely part of the point. I’ll cop to an error in my previous comment, though, namely that the proposition *does* make a claim w/r $n$ even; it doesn’t say anything about what happens when $n$ is odd, though.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion "$5n+7$ is even only if $n$ is odd" means "if $5n+7$ is even, then $n$ is odd". Instead of proving this, the easy way is to prove the contrapositive, i.e. that if $n$ is even, then $5n+7$ is odd, which is the second part of the argument you wrote.

The first part of the argument shows the reverse implication, so in the end we have an "if and only if": $5n+7$ is even if and only if $n$ is odd".